# WatchOS2 network Communication

Tags: ios, iphone, networking, udp, watchos-2

Does someone know if it is possible with the new WatchOS2 to manage for  UDP listener (to receive and send data) directly from the Watch without the use of the iPhone as support? I have an app with an UDP listener that I would like to transfer to the Watch to avoid communication between the device.

Comment: You should watch the Session videos.

Comment: Watch Session videos? Can you explain better?

Comment: In my case I need to ask to a remote device (PC or embedded system) some information using UDP messages but I don't know how to send out the UDP messages from the iPhone (but in the iPhone UDP socket are closed when in background) or from Watch : is in Watch OS2 possible?? directly to send UDP without using iPhone as bridge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Socket communication would not be possible directly from the Apple Watch because the CFNetwork framework is not one of the available frameworks in watchOS 2.

[Apple pre-release documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleWatch2TransitionGuide/LeverageSystemTechnologies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015234-CH8-SW1) states:

> Extensions built specifically for watchOS 2 have access to the following system frameworks:
>
> - ClockKit
> - Contacts
> - Core Data
> - Core Foundation
> - Core Graphics
> - Core Location
> - Core Motion
> - EventKit
> - Foundation
> - HealthKit
> - HomeKit
> - ImageIO
> - MapKit
> - Mobile Core Services
> - PassKit
> - Security
> - Watch Connectivity
> - WatchKit

Comment: Thanks, I hope it will possible in the final release.. because otherwise I can't develop my App :-(

Answer (score 4):

I believe you're going to want to watch 'Introducing Watch Connectivity' from WWDC 2015. They discuss different ways that Apple Watch can receive data, and one of those is directly from "the cloud" rather than through the iPhone.

[Here is the link](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=713)

I'm unsure how many people will be able to help you specifically with these abilities being so new, so if you figure it out please let us know how you did it. Good luck!

Comment: I need to install XCode7 on my MAC to start to study a solution... but unfortunately Xcode crash every time on my mac...

Answer (score 1):

I'm in a similar situation.  I had it working in WatchOS 1.0 using the WatchKit Extension that runs on the phone via a shared CommKit framework that I created that uses GCDAsyncSocket.  It relies on the iPhone to be paired and the code runs on the phone.

Today with WatchOS 2.0, the same would need to happen using the "Interative Messaging and Reachability" model.  It's in the video mentioned in the previous posts.

Basically, you will run the TCP/UDP code on the iPhone like with WatchOS 1.0 -- so you still need the host iPhone to be nearby.